# How to remove unique constraint for a model attribute of an abstract model after inheritance?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an abstract class as:

```
class AbstractExecutive(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True,
                              verbose_name='*Mobile')

   #other attributs not required....
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I am inheriting this class to create different instances like Client,Vendor etc. For a class instance Client, I require that the unique constraint is dropped, while it exists for other class objects. I am using postgresql 9.1 I I dropped the the client table constraint using psql, but since the model is inherited, it always has unique constraint on it. Please note the Client table has data and cannot be disturbed. How can I get rid of the constraint in the table. Client class model:

```
class Client(AbstractAddress,AbstractExecutive):

    number = models.CharField(max_length=10,verbose_name='number',
                                  unique=True)
    #other attributes...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to override the inherited `mobile` field of `Client`:

```
class Client(...):
    ...
Client._meta.get_field('mobile')._unique = False
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/165603/okm your solution also works as well as solution from http://stackoverflow.com/users/119071/serafeim Thx both. But I think yours is a better option, than playing with the table.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could this also be done by defining the uniqueness constraint in the model meta class in the concrete models and leaving it out of the abstract model class eg. through unique_together = ('fieldname',).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuanately this is not possible in django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted). You need to remove `mobile` from your abstract class and put it to the concrete classes (either with or without `unique`).

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/119071/serafeim Will removing the abstract class, and adding the attribute on the exisiting Client class with same attribute name, effect existing data of 'mobile' attribute of the Client model? Thx in advance

Comment: If you copy paste the the definition of the ``mobile`` field to the inheriting classes the database fields will be exactly the same. So don't worry, just do it (I've already done it without problems -- also, no new migrations will be created if you do this).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it wasn't possible with old Django versions, but now the solution is to re-define the attribute on the child class, without the `unique=True` constraint.

So in the given example, with the unique `mobile` attribute in the `AbstractExecutive` abstract model and that must not be `unique` in `Client` model:

**Your abstract class:**

```
class AbstractExecutive(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True,
                              verbose_name='*Mobile')

   #other attributs not required....
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

**The child non-abstract class:**

```
class Client(AbstractAddress, AbstractExecutive):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='*Mobile')

    #other attributes...
```

When generating the migrations, the `unique` constraint will be removed in `Client` model.